# Enable extension and fwidth in glsl

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm using webGL and I want to use `fwidth` as I did it in Three.js.
in .glsl file I've added an extension like this:

```
#ifndef GL_ES
// Non OpenGL ES devices doesnt support precision qualifiers, so we do
// nothing instead
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#else
// to have functions like fwidth for OpenGL ES or WebGL, the extension should
// be explicitly enabled.
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif
```

But I'm keep getting this errors:

```
Error compiling FRAGMENT_SHADER: WARNING: 0:14: '
' : extension directive should occur before any non-preprocessor tokens
WARNING: 0:14: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:47: 'fwidth' : no matching overloaded function found
```

If anyone knows how to fix this - would be great to get a hint.

Comment: Move the `extension` statement to the top of your file and outside the `ifdef`

Comment: I've moved it outside of #if and it seems to work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, the whole `ifdef` doesn't make any sense, [precision qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Precision_qualifiers) are always available.